# Performance impact of using statement in unit test

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing

I have a WCF service hosted locally exposing a basic method that returns the string value you pass to it.

I also have a unit test where I try to call the service 10000 times and I monitor the time it takes for the calls to complete.

The position of my using statement in my test is crucial and makes a big difference if placed incorrectly, however I don't understand why this happens.

Example 1: (35 seconds)

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestGetDataOutsideUsing()
    {
        const int count = 10000;
        var operations = new List<int>();
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            operations.Add(i);
        using (var proxy = new BasicHttpServiceClient())
        {
            var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(operations, x => { proxy.GetData(x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); });
            timer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0:###0.0000000} ms", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("{0:###0.0000000} per millisecond", (count / (decimal)timer.ElapsedMilliseconds));
            Console.WriteLine("{0:###0.0000000} per second", (count / ((decimal)timer.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000)));
            Console.WriteLine("{0:###0.0000000} per minute", (count / ((decimal)timer.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000 / 60)));
        }
    }
```

Example 2: (6.2 seconds)

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestGetDataInsideUsing()
    {
        const int count = 10000;
        var operations = new List<int>();
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            operations.Add(i);
        var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(operations, x =>
            {
                using (var proxy = new BasicHttpServiceClient())
                {
                    proxy.GetData(x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                }
            });
        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0:###0.0000000} ms", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("{0:###0.0000000} per millisecond", (count / (decimal)timer.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        Console.WriteLine("{0:###0.0000000} per second", (count / ((decimal)timer.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000)));
        Console.WriteLine("{0:###0.0000000} per minute", (count / ((decimal)timer.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000 / 60)));
    }
```

The only difference between the 1st and 2nd example is the position of the using statement. I would have thought that having the using statement inside the ForEach would take longer, but it actually proved otherwise.

Why is this, and which of the above examples is the accurate way to test this? Am I perhaps going about this test the wrong way?

All I want to do is make 10000 concurrent calls to my service and see how long it takes.

Comment: This is a bad practice wrapping client proxy instantiation in `using` statement, search stackoverflow for `"how to close client WCF proxy"`

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that the first example shares the same proxy across each thread so they're not executing in parallel?

Comment: @sll Thanks, I didn't know about this. Will read up on it and make sure the instantiation and disposal is done properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example, there is a single `Proxy` object; in the second example, there are multiple `Proxy` objects.

I think this is not directly linked with the `using` statement, but how it is used. In the first example, `Proxy` object becomes a bottleneck for the parallel operation.

Answer (score 2):

These are two very different things:

- In the first example, you are running multiple threads over a single proxy object, which effectively serializes the processing<sup>1</sup> and destroys the parallelism.
- In the second example, each thread has its own proxy object, which allows it to run independently from (and concurrently to) other threads.

The amount of work is more-less equal<sup>2</sup>, yet the second example finishes sooner simply because more of the work can be done in parallel.

---

*<sup>1</sup> I'm assuming there is a lock somewhere in there, otherwise you have a race condition.*

*<sup>2</sup> Disregarding the cost of creating all these proxies.*

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I understand this better now. Example 1 is then irrelevant for what I need the test to do.